# Returning a POST result from an AJAX call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is the following in JS:

```
function getSuccessForTest(testName,version,fromRev,toRev,res) {        

        var params = {
            "methodToRun":"getSuccessForTest",
            "version":version,
            "startRev":fromRev,
            "endRev":toRev,
            "testName":testName     
        };          
        $.post("Stats.php", params,function(data){
            return parseInt(data.toString(),10);
        }, "json");         
    }   

    getSuccessForTest(data[i],version,fromRev,toRev,res);
```

What am I doing wrong ? whenever I make the call to getSuccessForTest, I get the POST result in Stats.php but the value isn't returned to the calling function.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+return+value+from+ajax+call

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the result from JSONP call outside the function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341810/how-to-return-the-result-from-jsonp-call-outside-the-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's beacuse value is returned to the anonymous function (function(data){...). Use callbacks. Try this:

```
function getSuccessForTest(testName,version,fromRev,toRev,res, callback) {        

    var params = {
        "methodToRun":"getSuccessForTest",
        "version":version,
        "startRev":fromRev,
        "endRev":toRev,
        "testName":testName     
    };          
    $.post("Stats.php", params,function(data){
        callback(parseInt(data.toString(),10));
    }, "json");         
    }   

    getSuccessForTest(data[i],version,fromRev,toRev,res, function(res) {
        alert(res)
    } );
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not working because the return is in the callback function given to $.post as a parameter. Since you're dealing with an ajax request which is asynchronous you need to use a callback for getSuccessForTest as well. Try this:

```
function getSuccessForTest(testName,version,fromRev,toRev,res, callback) {        

    var params = {
        "methodToRun":"getSuccessForTest",
        "version":version,
        "startRev":fromRev,
        "endRev":toRev,
        "testName":testName     
    };          
    $.post("Stats.php", params,function(data){
        callback(parseInt(data.toString(),10));
        //return parseInt(data.toString(),10);
    }, "json");         
}   

getSuccessForTest(data[i],version,fromRev,toRev,res, function (data) {
    alert(data); // This would be the value you wanted to return
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use `echo` when you are return from stats.php. if this is not solving your issue then I would like to know what is the return method you are using for your ajax call handling script.

Comment: There *might* be a problem on the server side as well, but the actual problem is that you cannot simply "return" the value form an Ajax call, due it asynchronous nature.

Answer (score 0):

```
return parseInt(data.toString(),10);
```

You cant return like that.
either assign in some global variable or do process there with data